# Using specifyModel from quantmod package within a loop

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to replicate the stock prediction case study from the Data Mining with R book, and am trying to place some of the code within a loop so I can deal with more than one stock. However, I cannot figure out how to get the specifyModel function to work within the loop. I want to calculate a number of technical indicators for each stock, and eventually use a random forest to select the most useful ones. Below is some example code.

```
library(quantmod)

# The list of stocks I want to investigate 
stock.symbols = c("MMM", "IBM")

# Download daily stock prices to global environment 
getSymbols(stock.symbols, src = "yahoo", quotes = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted"), from = "2011-01-01", to = "2012-01-01")

# "Custom" indicator functions 
myAroon = function(x) aroon(Cl(x))[,1]
myADX = function(x) ADX(HLC=x)[,4]

# Try to create quantmod model for each stock  
for(i in stock.symbols)
{
  my.model = specifyModel(Cl(MMM) ~ myAroon(MMM) + myADX(MMM)) # this line works - looks up MMM in global environment
  #    my.model = specifyModel(Cl(i) ~ myAroon(i) + myADX(i)) # I would like something like this
}
```

I understand that if you refer to the stock by its symbol, for example "MMM", specifyModel looks it up in the current workspace. I would like to know how to make this more general. At the minute I am getting the following error:

```
no applicable method for 'as.xts' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I have tried going through the documentation for specifyModel, but to no avail (it doesn't seem to be the most widely used function in the world). I have also tried using get() and as.name(). I realise I may be doing something completely wrong here, so apologies in advance! Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `get` works for me.

```
my.model <- list()
for(i in stock.symbols)
{
  stock <- get(i)
  my.model = c(my.model, specifyModel(Cl(stock) ~ myAroon(stock) + myADX(stock)) )
}

lapply(my.model, function(x) head(x@model.data))
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be exactly what I wanted. I was using something like Cl(get(i)), which I assume was confusing R somehow. Thanks again for the speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative/supplement to shadow's answer, you could specify your own environment to store the results in:

```
data.env <- new.env()
getSymbols(stock.symbols, env=data.env, src = "yahoo",
   quotes = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted"),
   from = "2011-01-01", to = "2012-01-01")

for(i in stock.symbols){
   stock <- get(i,env=data.env)
   ...
   }
```

The advantage of this is: a) cleaner (no chance of overriding something in your current environment); b) future-proof. The documentation is saying that from quantmod 0.5 the default behaviour of getSymbols will change.

Speaking of which, the new default behaviour will be to return the data, rather than write it to an environment. You can get that behaviour now by one of:

- Pass env as NULL
- Pass auto.assign=FALSE
- In your options file specify `getSymbols.auto.assign` as `FALSE`

Comment: I think in 0.5 the idea will be to use `loadSymbols()` if you want to store the data in an environment, and `getSymbols()` if you want the data returned.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had been using a separate environment in my real code, but omitted this from my example above for simplicity.